# Random Survival Forests (RSF) for longitudinal data and multivariate outcomes

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, supervised-learning

I am trying to find out if there is any validated model out there that covers RSF with time-varying covariates and multivariate outcomes (such as competing risks).

Would this just be an extension to the publicly available RSF by changing the splitting criteria?